# Direct image of a locally constant sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be the open disk of radius $1$ and $U$ the punctured open disk of radius $1$ at the origin. If $u\in U$ and $\pi_1(U,u)=\mathbb{Z}$ is the fundamental group, then we know that categorically, locally constant sheaves on $U$ are the same as $\pi_1(U,u)$-modules through the functor $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}_u.$

Now, let $F$ be any $\mathbb{Z}$-module, $\mathcal{F}$ the corresponding sheaf, and $j:U\to X$ the embedding. Why is it true that
$$
(j_\star\mathcal{F})_{(0,0)}=F^{\mathbb{Z}},
$$
where $j_\star$ is the direct image functor.

I tried to compute this using the definition of $j_\star$ and the direct-limit definition of the stalk, but I have no idea how to compute $\mathcal{F}(V\setminus\{(0,0)\})$ where $V$ is a neighborhood of $(0,0).$ As far as I can tell, even if $V$ is small enough, $\mathcal{F}|_{V\setminus\{(0,0)\}}$ isn't a constant sheaf if $F^\mathbb{Z}\neq F.$

An answer or a reference would be great. I am trying to learn this algebraic topology example so I can apply the same reasoning/intuition to the étale case for the punctured line.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about your question? The fact that you mention modules over the fundamental group reminds me of local systems rather than locally constant sheaves. Also as you wrote a neighbourhood of the origin, even with the origin removed, is connected so since a locally constant sheaf is the same as a sheaf of locally constant functions, and these are constant on a connected subset

Comment: Hello @LouisHainaut. I cannot say I am sure. This is Example 8.5  of Milne's "Lecture notes on etale cohomology". I  could have misunderstood though. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. If I understand correctly a locally constant sheaf is the same as a local system, I got it confused with a constant sheaf so it did not make so much sense

Comment: Maybe you can try looking at an example to try and figure out what is happening. My go-to example is (a variation of) the Möbius band, corresponding to the module $\mathbb Z$ with action $n\bullet x = (-1)^n x$. You can verify that indeed for any such open set V you don't get a constant sheaf; if you loop once around the origin you multiply by (-1), so you can have a section if and only if multiplying by (-1) gives the same element, so if and only if you take something in the invariant $F^{\mathbb Z}$

Comment: @LouisHainaut. Sorry for the late reply. I will work out that example and see if I can figure out the rigorous details behind it. I know that we will not get a constant sheaf, intuitively speaking, but I'll see if I can get the details right.

Comment: No problem, take the time you need to understand this example. Also a simplifying trick is that in order to compute the stalk (or more generally any directed colimit), you don't need to consider all neighbourhoods $V$, but only a cofinal family, for example here you can take the family of discs around the origin with radius $\epsilon$, or an even smaller family is to only consider radius $1/n$. For those you verify easily that $(j_{\star}\mathcal F)(V) = \mathcal F(U)$

Comment: @LouisHainaut 
This took me a bit long, but I found these notes {https://www.math.lsu.edu/~pramod/tc/07s-7280/notes3.pdf} to understand how local systems correspond to representations. Connecting this with your comments, I have finally understood why this works. Please make this an answer so I can accept it. Thank you.